# Are there infinitely many real multiplication fields of abelian surfaces over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, modular-forms, abelian-varieties, rational-points

> Do there exist infinitely many real quadratic fields $F$ such that there is an abelian surface $A$ over $\mathbb Q$ whose ring of endomorphisms, tensored with $\mathbb Q$, is $F$?
>
> Do there exist infinitely many real quadratic fields $F$ that are the coefficient field of a weight $2$ classical holomorphic eigenforms over $\mathbb Q$?

Of course the analogue of the first question for imaginary quadratic fields and elliptic curves the answer is yes. By studying the Hilbert surfaces, maybe one can prove conditionally on Bombieri-Lang that there are finitely many $F$ for which there are infinitely many isomorphism classes of such surfaces, but this of course is a long way off.

Comment: @reuns Yes, I do.

Comment: @reuns What is a weight 2 Maass form? In any case my interest is with abelian varieties, and no Maass forms are expected to correspond to abelian varieties.

Comment: There is a conjecture of Coleman asserting that there are only finitely many such real quadratic fields, see *Which quaternion algebras act on a modular abelian variety* by Victor Rotger. Also it is known that abelian surfaces with real multiplication are modular, so unless I'm missing something the two questions are equivalent.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault I would be willing to accept such an answer explaining that it's a known open problem.

Comment: This question was earlier asked here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/207935/6518 Should we close one of these?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A conjecture of Coleman asserts that only finitely many rings arise as the endomorphism ring of an abelian variety of given dimension defined over a number field of given degree. See [1] for an account of this conjecture. In your case, the relevant conjecture is denoted there by $C(1,2)$. To my knowledege, the only results on Coleman's conjecture in dimension >1 concern CM abelian varieties.

Regarding your second question, Ribet has shown that Serre's conjecture on representations of the absolute Galois group of $\mathbf{Q}$ [2, Conjecture (3.2.4)] implies that every abelian variety of $\mathrm{GL}_2$-type over $\mathbf{Q}$ is a quotient of $J_1(N)$ for some $N \geq 1$, see [3, Theorem 4.4]. Serre's conjecture is now a theorem of Khare-Wintenberger [4, Theorem 5.1] so that your second question is equivalent to the first.

**[1]** Bruin, Flynn, Gonzalez, Rotger, *On finiteness conjectures for endomorphism algebras of abelian surfaces*. Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 141 (2006), No. 3, 383-408.

**[2]** Serre, *Sur les représentations modulaires de degré 2 de $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q})$*. Duke Math. J. 54 (1987), 179-230.

**[3]** Ribet, *Abelian varieties over $\mathbf{Q}$ and modular forms*. Modular curves and abelian varieties, 241–261, Progr. Math., 224, Birkhäuser, 2004.

**[4]** Khare, *Serre's conjecture and its consequences*, Japan. J. Math. 5 (2010), 103–125.